# Vue3 scoped classes are not applied for elements not declared in the template

Tags: vue.js

I have a single-file vue3 component.
Its template looks like this.

```
<template>
  <div ref="elements"></div>
</template>
```

I have scoped styles in the same file:

```
<style scoped>
.el {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

Now I want to add element in the script.

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  mounted() {
    const div = this.$refs.elements;

    const el = document.createElement("div");
    el.setAttribute("class", "el");
    el.innerText = "Hello World!";

    div.appendChild(el);
  },
};
</script>
```

The result shows that the element is not styled according to the class in the scoped styles.
Is there a way to apply styling to the elements added through script, while keeping styles in the scope?

Answer (score 0):

After some research this seems to be an answer.

Vue scoped styling is the internal Vue feature. So, there should be a way to distinguish same class names on different components. Vue does it by adding a special id to each class name. You can find it by inspecting elements in the browser (e.g. `data-v-a2c3afe`).

When building a component, Vue processes its template and properly tracks only nodes you have declared for rendering there. It does not know anything it might get from somewhere. It actually makes sense and pushes you to write everything you expect to see in the template, so that it does not happen that you suddenly see something wrong in the DOM (especially if you are taking someone's code).

I have rewritten code, so that I still have scoped styles, but with no elements appending from the script and the code now allows to clearly see what is being rendered. This is probably the property of any framework - it makes you to stick to some patterns, so that everyone in the team/community knows what behavior to expect and writes more consistent code.